# FileMaker: Getting a specific related record in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: relationship, filemaker

Suppose that I have two tables, A and B.  A has an ID field, and B has a ID, Value, and Title field.  The two ID fields are related, so that there is a one-to-many relationship between A and B.

What I want to do is add a Calculation field in A to retrieve the Title from the related B record for a specific Value.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you might do this, depending on what you are trying to achieve:

```
A::index ---< B::indexOfA
```

**Relationship Sort Order**

If you create a new Calculation field in A that with the calculation = B::Title the first record (by sort order) will be used.

Example: B has a field B::recordDate and you always want the latest recordDate regardless of the order the records were entered in. You would modify the A::index ---< B::indexOfA relationship to be sorted by recordDate descending. Your A::titleFromB calculation field would be:

```
B::Title
```

**GetNthRecord**

http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/func_ref3.33.10.html

If you want a particular record number from the relationship to B, you can use the GetNthRecord function.

Example: You always want to display the 2nd record of the relationship to B. Your A::titleFromB calculation field would be:

```
GetNthRecord(B::Title ; 2)
```

**ExecuteSQL**

In FileMaker 12 you can use an ExecuteSQL calculation.

Example: Say you know the B::index of the record you want to show the title of. Your A::titleFromB calculation field would be:

```
ExecuteSQL("SELECT Title from B WHERE index = ?"; ¶ ; "," ; <field, variable or string with index of B> )
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you want to structure your relationship is with each A and B having their own unique ID field. Then in B, have an id_a field (or something like that) where you can base your relationship.

From there I echo what pft221 says about ExecuteSQL. That's been a great function for me. It would be something like this:

`ExecuteSQL ( "SELECT Title FROM B WHERE id_a =? and title = ?"; ""; ""; <id_a value>; <title value> )`

You could also do an inner join but that seems to be a bit more trouble than it's worth.